# Replace character in MongoDB collection without saving changes.

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a MongoDB collection of `companies` and `models` in following format:

```
[{company:'Any company', models:['Model1','model2','model3']},
 ...
{company:'Any-company', models:['model83','Model-abc','MODEL43']}]
```

As you can see some of `company` or `model` names are upper case or written with dash symbol.

I want to save this collection into variable, and I need it to be Lower Case and without dashes.

I did it with just `mongoose find` and `for loop` like so:

```
mongoose.model('Company', companySchema).find({}, function(err, docs) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        var companyLowerCase = docs;
        for(var i=0;i<companyLowerCase.length;i++) {
            companyLowerCase[i].company = companyLowerCase[i].company.replace(/-/g, " ").toLowerCase();
            for(var j=0;j<companyLowerCase[i].models.length;j++) {
                companyLowerCase[i].models[j] = companyLowerCase[i].models[j].replace(/-/g, " ").toLowerCase();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

But I'm wondering if it is possible to achieve with MongoDB. I found that you can lower case you values like so:

```
db.inventory.aggregate([{
   $project:
     {
       item: { $toLower: "$item" },
       description: { $toLower: "$description" }
     }
 }]);
```

**But can you replace `"-"` on `" "` with MongoDB? If you can, then what request should I send to the MongoDB to achieve my goal?**

**NOTE:** Collection in database should not change. Modification must be only save in variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can since MongoDB doesn't have a replace operator for `$project`

Comment: @sascha this does answer the question - there is  no replace operator so the user can't do what he wishes in plain Mongo

Comment: This was an automated comment while reviewing answers. I guess I mixed something here ... Ignore it.